# Getting dataframe directly from JSON-file?

Tags: json, r

First, let me thank everybody who contributes to Stackoverflow and R! I'm one of those R-users who is not so good at programming, but bravely try to use it for work, so the issue below is probably trivial...

Here's the problem. I need to import files in JSON-format to R:

```
# library(plyr)
# library(RJSONIO)
# lstJson <- fromJSON("JSON_test.json")        #This is the file I read
# dput(lstJson)                                              #What I did to get the txtJson below, for the benefit of testing.

txtJson <- structure(list(version = "1.1", result = structure(list(warnings = structure(list(), class = "AsIs"), fields = list(structure(list(info = "", rpl = 15, name = "time", type = "timeperiod"), .Names = c("info", "rpl", "name", "type")), structure(list(info = "", name = "object", type = "string"), .Names = c("info", "name", "type")), structure(list(info = "Counter1", name = "Counter1", type = "int"), .Names = c("info", "name", "type")), structure(list( info = "Counter2", name = "Counter2", type = "int"), .Names = c("info", "name", "type"))), timeout = 180, name = NULL, data = list( list(list("2011-05-01 17:00", NULL), list("Total", NULL), list(8051, NULL), list(44, NULL)), list(list("2011-05-01 17:15", NULL), list("Total", NULL), list(8362, NULL), list( 66, NULL))), type = "AbcDataSet"), .Names = c("warnings", "fields", "timeout", "name", "data", "type"))), .Names = c("version", "result"))

dfJson <- ldply(txtJson, data.frame)
```

What I need is a data frame similar to this:

```
time  object  Counter1  Counter2  
2011-05-01 17:00  Total  8051  44  
2011-05-01 17:15  Total  8362  66
```

But instead I get

```
"Error in data.frame("2011-05-01 17:00", NULL, check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"
```

I get the same error if I use the lstJson.

I'm not sure if `RJSONIO` is supposed to be "smart enough" to parse files like this, or if I have to manually read the first line of the file, set column-types etc. The reason I'm not using CSV is that I want to "automatically" get dates in date-format, etc.

Thanks,
/Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the structure of txtJson you see that all of the useful bits are in txtJson$result$data:

```
> sapply( txtJson$result$data, unlist )
     [,1]               [,2]              
[1,] "2011-05-01 17:00" "2011-05-01 17:15"
[2,] "Total"            "Total"           
[3,] "8051"             "8362"            
[4,] "44"               "66"              
> t(sapply( txtJson$result$data, unlist ))
     [,1]               [,2]    [,3]   [,4]
[1,] "2011-05-01 17:00" "Total" "8051" "44"
[2,] "2011-05-01 17:15" "Total" "8362" "66"
> as.data.frame(t(sapply( txtJson$result$data, unlist )) )
                V1    V2   V3 V4
1 2011-05-01 17:00 Total 8051 44
2 2011-05-01 17:15 Total 8362 66
```

In the process of gettting these as unlisted vectors and then passing to 'as.data.frame' they are now all class 'factor', so there is probably additional effort to re-class() these values. You can instead use:

```
data.frame(t(sapply( txtJson$result$data, unlist )) ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And they would all be 'character'

As far as importing CSV files, read.table()'s colClasses argument will accept "POSIXlt" or "POSIXct" as known types. The rule I believe is that there must an as.*_* method available. Here's a minimal example:

```
> read.table(textConnection("2011-05-01 17:00"), sep=",", colClasses="POSIXct")
                   V1
1 2011-05-01 17:00:00
```