# unlist and transpose

Tags: r, plyr

After using sapply(data, unlist), I have what I think is a matrix of vectors or maybe it's still a list. The output looks like:

```
 [[index1]]     
  c1  
  "value"  
  c2  
  "value"   
  c3    
  "value"  
  [[index2]]  
  c1  
  "value"  
  c2  
  "value"    
  c3  
  "value"
```

My desired output is for each index to become a row in a data frame with "c1", "c2", and "c3" as columns. I already tried a simple transpose- t(). I would imagine that I could do this using reshape or plyr, but I can't figure it out.

Note: My question is very similar to [Getting dataframe directly from JSON-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526646/getting-dataframe-directly-from-json-file), but notice that after sapply the columns contain vectors.

Comment: You can try `str` or `dput` on the result to see what it is. See `?str` and `?dput` for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `rbind` to format your `sapply` output:

```
a=list(a=1:3, b=4:6)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, a))
```